# Create intensity of colors in ggplot2 - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to have the colour intensity based on the values of the variable in ggplot2 / ggmap. I used the following code,

```
 print(ggmap(m) + 
                geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size = variable2, 
                               colour = variable1)
                               size = 3, pch = 20, data=combined1) + 
                scale_colour_continuous( low = "red", high = "green"))
```

But the problem here is, there are some extreme values like 80,70 whereas the average values are around 10-20. This is not allowing me to visualize the entire graph properly because most of them fall under one bucket. Therefore I created a bucket variable here,

```
combined1 = combined1 %>% mutate(bucket = ifelse(variable1 >= 0 & variable1< 5 ,'Less than 5',
                                        ifelse(variable1>= 5  & variable1< 10 ,'5-10',
                                               ifelse(variable1>= 10  & variable1< 15 ,'10-15',
                                                      ifelse(variable1>= 15  & variable1< 20 ,'15-20', 'Above 20')))))
```

and then I wanted to try the same ,

```
 print(ggmap(m) + 
                geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size = variable2, 
                               colour = bucket)
                               size = 3, pch = 20, data=combined1) )
```

This works well, but it is not like a intensity based graph. It is fixed colours. So I tried the following,

```
 print(ggmap(m) + 
                geom_point(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size = variable2, 
                               colour = bucket)
                               size = 3, pch = 20, data=combined1) + 
                scale_colour_continuous( low = "red", high = "green"))
```

But when I try this, I am getting,

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I even tried `scale_colour_discrete` still the same error pops up. Can anybody help me in getting the intensity graph for the buckets.

Thanks

Comment: try scale_colour_brewer for some good intensity colour scales. And see cut() as an alternative to lots of ifelse statementes

Comment: @RichardTelford How can we do that to move from pink to dark red? They are very fixed palette's right?

Comment: scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Reds")

Comment: I identified the Oranges palette which suits my need. But I have a slight problem here. The order it takes is 10-15, 15-20, 5-10, Above20 and Less than 5. Is there a way we can change the order ?

Comment: The basic idea is to show the lowest to highest or highest to lowest. But again this does not solve my problem here. :(

Comment: You have a `factor`, which by default is ordered alphabetically. You can use `reorder()` to change the levels based on a value column, or specify the order explicitly in `factor()`, or if you use `cut` as suggested they will already be in the right order.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :) Will try that and see.